# Python- hex to bytes for passing to a socket address

Tags: python, byte

I am trying to send a byte command to an RFID connected to a Raspberry Pi.
the code i'm using is

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.178', 4001)
sock.connect(server_address)

cmd=bytes.fromhex('A00372')
sock.sendall(cmd)
s=sock.recv(1024 * 4)
print(s)
```

if i check what cmd is, it is returned as b'\xa0\x03r' instead of b'\xa0\x03\x72'

any help will be appreciated

I've tried researching but with not much luck including
binascii.hexlify(cmd).decode('utf-8')

Comment: Bytes that can be represented as Ascii characters are shown as such. `cmd` has the right content. If you don't like the **representation**, you can use `hexlify` or other functions to create another representation.

Comment: When python displays bytes, it will convert bytes that correspond to ascii text into that character. `'r' == '\x72`, so all is well, at least from the byte string point of view. Is there any reason why you need a different display?

Comment: this command should get a response from the RFID device of the firmware but it seems to hang. with cmd="A006FF8B010001CE" which give me b'\xa0\x06\xff\x8b\x01\x00\x01\xce' works to give me the tag number, so i assumed that 'r' was causing the hang up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.178', 4001)
sock.connect(server_address)

cmd = bytes.fromhex('A0 03 72')
sock.sendall(cmd)
s = sock.recv(1024 * 4)
print(s)
```

Does this worked?

Comment: no it didn't, but reading protocol guide it looks like i'm missing a couple of byte from my string, and address and checksum so it should of been "A0 03 FF 72 EC" and that works. Sorry  for my error but you have cleared some thing up.